# How to load user written extension automatically in windbg

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

I am having windbg kernel debugger attached to a virtual machine. I have loaded a user written extension dll (.load DLL). Whenever virtual machine reboots (.reboot), it unloads all extensions and after VM reboot, it never load them back. I have to load it every time.

Is there any way, I can tell windbg to load my extension even after reboot (or don't unload it at all?) Not sure if later is possible. Is there any workaround?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

well typing or selecting from history **.load foo.dll** is not such a big annoyance
or `typing foo!myblah`  loads your extension and executes the command and as such it shouldn't be a big deal

when you reboot it starts a new session so all user modifications do not persist

but if you think you need some automation for such you can employ sxe command 
prior to reboot like

```
sxe -c ".load mysuperduperext.dll;gc" ibp ; .reboot
```

this assumes that you have put your extsnion dll in default search paths
viz **winext/%PATH%**

if it is in some directory that is not in default search path

use one of the various options like setting the _NT_DEBUGGER_EXTESNION_PATH 
prior to executing windbg / kd

```
:\>cat runwindkd.bat
set  _NT_DEBUGGER_EXTENSION_PATH=.\myexts
.\windbg -k com:pipe,port=\\.\pipe\debugpipe,resets=0,reconnect -c ".load myext.dll"
```

this will add the directory to default search path

```
kd> .extpath
Extension search path is: .\myexts;E:\wind
```

Comment: I just modified the shortcut path and appended `-c ".load myextention"` that worked like a charm